# After updating to Sonarlint 2.4.0 it's not working anymore in Eclipse Mars

Tags: java, sonarqube, eclipse-mars, sonarlint, sonarlint-eclipse

I am currently integrating sonarlint to my project. I installed sonarlint 2.3 in Eclipse Mars a month ago and it works. But I temporarily disabled it in order to work freely. I read that sonarlint has a new version (2.4.0) and I updated it. And after restarting eclipse I can't find where to enable it again. But when I try to see it in installed plugins it is installed. I tried to uninstall it and then reinstall it but it does not work. It's eating my time now and I've research a lot but nothing seems to have my problem. If someone can help, it will be my pleasure. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What if you go under _Window - Show View - Other_ ? If SonarLint is there then write some ugly code and it should start flagging issues.

Comment: Yes @Nicolas I tried it, and there is no SonarLint there.

Comment: What do you mean by "temporarily disabled"? Did you uncheck the "automatic analysis" in project settings? Also you may try to start Eclipse with -clean flag, sometimes it helps.

Comment: @JulienH.-SonarSourceTeam I unchecked the run SonarLint automatically in the project>properties>sonarlint, So that I can work freely but when I am trying to enable it again i cannot find the sonarlint anymore. Although it is installed in my IDE. I've reinstalled it but I still can't find the sonarlint.

Comment: The most common case when SonarLint doesn't appear in UI menus while it is reported as installed is when you are running Eclipse with a JRE < 8. Please double check that you are still using JRE 8+ to run Eclipse after your migration to Mars. You can look at Help -> About Eclipse -> Installation details -> Configuration. Check value of java.version property.